# Does an HTML image map scale up/down with the image?

Tags: html

I know that if I have an image, I can put "hotlinks" on it using HTML image maps.
However, if I re-size the image (e.g., `<img src="my_image.jpg" width="20" height="40" />` becomes `<img src="my_image.jpg" width="10" height="30" />`), will the image map scale with the changed dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the image-maps work with absolute positions based in your image, so if the first position was 20x40, when you rescale your image, that hot-spot will be gone.